# Trouble: A PC with win7 and Delphi XE6, and Mac OSX in virtualbox on the same PC

Tags: windows, macos, delphi

I'm having difficulties in creating a new Delphi target platform OS X.

The machine I'm using is a PC with Win7. On this PC I have MAC OS X installed on VirtualBox, this virtual machine with Mac OS X works perfectly.

In Win7 I installed Embarcadero Delphi XE6, and developed a software and want to compile it for Windows and for Mac.

But when I try to add a new target platform OS X, Delphi asks me the IP address or name of the remote machine, so I have installed the RAD PAServer XE6 in virtual machine, and pressed the 'I' key to know the ip virtual machine, and gave me the ip 10.0.2.15, so I put that IP in Delphi on Win7, but when I test the connection, error appears:

`Connection to '10.0.2.15' on port 64211 failed. Make sure the that 'Platform Assistent Server' is running on the host machine and is configuered to use port 64211.`

What is failing me ... some settings? I'll have some extra software active in win7 to bridge with VirtualBox?

Please someone help me, my application is almost ready and wanted to test it on the Mac OSX system.

I have searched on the internet, but can only find a Mac OS X machine working with Delphi XE6 on WinXP virtual machine, but my case is the opposite, it is a Win7 machine with Delphi XE6; with Mac OS X in a virtual machine.

Comment: May be that I am wrong, but AFAIK running OSX in a non Apple hardware based virtual environment is not covered by the license. So I guess you will not find many people with this sort of setup.

Comment: This is kinda like posting a question asking if people can help you hotwire your neighbor's car. If it's worth your time to develop stuff for OS X, then invest in a Mac Mini or some other inexpensive and *LEGAL* OS X platform. You might even be violating the terms of your Delphi license as well by running PAServer on an unlicensed platform. Personally speaking, I do ALL of my dev work on a Mac, and run Windows (and Delphi) inside of a VMWare VM. Works like a charm!

Comment: Are you tried making a ping to the OSX VM machine? Also check the firewall in both machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already solved the problem, is very simple:

1 - In VirtualBox, Settings, Network, choose Bridged Adapter, so that
    virtual machine is in the same subnet mask.

2 - In the virtual machine with Mac OS X, run the Rad PAServer, press the
    'I' to see the IP.

3 - Go to firewall rules and add in communication, the IP that appears in
    PAServer and the port.

4 - In Delphi add a platform, OS X or iOS X, put the IP and port of
    virtual machine, and works to 100%.

Thank you ...