# Reg. iOs mobile app developement hardware requirements using Delphi XE7

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I'm using Delphi XE7 for developing mobile application. And some how, I have learnt how to create and test the Android mobile application using Delphi XE7 and for developing and testing Android application, just one Android mobile is enough. And I need to know the hardware requirements for developing and testing iOs mobile applications. And currently I'm having Windows 64 bit Os. Is it possible to develop and test, if I'm having Mac Os which is Virtual Os and iPhone device in my hand.  And in the Virtual OS, I need to install Xcode and the required packages. Please confirm me once should I need compulsory MAC book for developing iOs mobile application using Delphi XE7.?
Please provide me the solution.

Comment: The requirements are documented

Comment: Yeah. But can I use the Virtual Mac Os for developing iOs application.? Or should I need MAC book.?

Comment: Here's a question similar to yours - the user was able to get Mac OS X working on a virtual box environment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24597275/trouble-a-pc-with-win7-and-delphi-xe6-and-mac-osx-in-virtualbox-on-the-same-pc

Comment: You can use MacInCloud as well which is just a user account that you rent on someone's Mac server somewhere. You deploy via the Mac which compiles in Xcode and leaves you with an IPA file. You can then install the IPA file on your local device with Itunes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mac OS X is bound to the Apple hardware. The only way to make OS X run in a virtual machine is to hack it. There are several solutions available e.g. [here](http://www.macbreaker.com/2012/07/mountain-lion-virtualbox.html) and [here](http://lifehacker.com/5938332/how-to-run-mac-os-x-on-any-windows-pc-using-virtualbox).

I am however sure that you will end up being frustrated about spending too much time on tweaking Delphi and the hacked OS X - even **with** Apple hardware there can be plenty of frustrations! For example there are updates to Xcode all the time and some of them breaks things. If you also have to tweak OS X every time you need to update, you would wish you bought the hardware.

I can recommend buying a Mac Mini ($499), it is the cheapest way to get a Mac. To minimize cost, you can simply connect it to the same monitor as your windows computer and just switch input on the monitor when you are working on the Mac. I have done that and it works very well.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to your development PC, you need the following to develop multi-device applications for iOS:

- A Mac running OS X
- An iOS device, connected to your Mac by USB cable

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/IOS_Mobile_Application_Development

Comment: OP is asking if he can run OS X in a virtual machine on his PC, or is he required to buy Apple hardware?